# How to show a confirm popup, while redirecting to new route in AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-router

I want to show a confirmation popup(with Yes & No buttons) when there is a route change in my angularJs App.

I tried this way. This event is called each time before the route change, But this function is not restricting the user from going to a different route, even when the user has selected 'NO'

```
 $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event) {
      if (vm.counterObject.myList.length > 0) {
        var answer = confirm("Are you sure?")
        if (answer) {
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      }
    });
```

Any suggestion on where am I wrong?

Comment: Is this for select specific route(s) or do you really want to intercept all navigation with this confirm?

Comment: @Kinglish this is for a specific route only. Not for all the navigation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got this working in my test angularjs app. This is an approach I adapted from [Ben Nadel's site](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2808-asking-the-user-to-confirm-location-or-route-changes-in-angularjs.htm). I decided to just paste the whole controller here

Edit: What is different from the last approach is the OOO (order of operations) in this function. The issue was angular didn't get a chance to `$digest` the update in time when we are allowing the `$location.path()` to go through. It was still hitting the event listener. `stopWatchingLocation()` cancels that listener but due to the wiring of events, we have to allow angular to digest that.

So essentially, this made the difference in the `proceedWithLocationChange` function:

Running this first: `stopWatchingLocation();`

then

```
$timeout(() => {$location.path( targetPath ).search( targetSearch ).hash( targetHash )},10);
}
```

it worked great in my environment

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myApp.view1', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/view1', {
    templateUrl: 'view1/view1.html',
    controller: 'View1Ctrl'
  });
}])

.controller('View1Ctrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$timeout', function($scope, $location, $timeout) {


$scope.currentLocation = $location.url();
$scope.myList =  [1,2,3]
$scope.$on(
    "$locationChangeSuccess",
    function handleLocationChangeSuccessEvent( event ) {
        $scope.currentLocation = $location.url();
    }
);

var startWatchingTimer = $timeout( startWatchingForLocationChanges, 0, false );
var stopWatchingLocation = null;

function handleLocationChangeStartEvent( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var targetPath = $location.path();
    var targetSearch = $location.search();
    var targetHash = $location.hash();

    if ($scope.myList.length > 0) {
        if (confirm('Leave the page?')) {
            proceedWithLocationChange(targetPath, targetSearch, targetHash)
        }
    } else {
        proceedWithLocationChange(targetPath, targetSearch, targetHash)
    }
}

function proceedWithLocationChange(targetPath, targetSearch, targetHash) {
    stopWatchingLocation();
    $timeout(() => {$location.path( targetPath ).search( targetSearch ).hash( targetHash )},10);
}




function startWatchingForLocationChanges() {
    console.log("watching");
    stopWatchingLocation = $scope.$on( "$locationChangeStart", handleLocationChangeStartEvent );
}

}]);
```

Comment: I'm facing 2 issue with this soltuion. 
1- I'm not able to access my ```counterObject.myList``` 
2- This resolve is called, both while navigating into '/deals', & navigating out of '/deals'. Whereas I wanted this to be called while navigating away only

Comment: @BlizZard - completely new answer. Give a looksee, hope it helps

Comment: I really appreciate the quick recode. I tried this new solution..but it's showing the confirm popup..and navigating to another tab even if I click "Yes" or "No" on the confirmation box

Comment: Is it navigating before you choose yes or no? or after?

Comment: After I choose Yes

Comment: ok. I'll test it tonight. I'm curious how to make this work.

Comment: @BlizZard - I got it working in my environment, give this adjusted code a try. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to show a modal from a page-partial looks like this

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="container">
  <button ng-click="toggleModal('OK')" class="btn btn-default">Success</button>
  <modal visible="showModal">
      Any additional data / buttons
  </modal>
</div>
```

Have a directive to show and hide the modal.

```
mymodal.directive('modal', function () {
    return {
      template: '<div class="modal fade">' + 
          '<div class="modal-dialog">' + 
            '<div class="modal-content">' + 
              '<div class="modal-header">' + 
                '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + 
                '<h4 class="modal-title">{{ buttonClicked }} clicked!!</h4>' + 
              '</div>' + 
              '<div class="modal-body" ng-transclude></div>' + 
            '</div>' + 
          '</div>' + 
        '</div>',
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      replace:true,
      scope:true,
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
          scope.$watch(attrs.visible, function(value){
          if(value == true)
            $(element).modal('show');
          else
            $(element).modal('hide');
        });

        $(element).on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
          scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = true;
          });
        });

        $(element).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
          scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = false;
          });
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

And finally when you click a button, you want to redirect the user.

```
mymodal.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.showModal = false;
    $scope.buttonClicked = "";
    $scope.toggleModal = function(btnClicked){
        $scope.buttonClicked = btnClicked;
        $scope.showModal = !$scope.showModal;
        if(btnClicked == "OK") {
        $window.location.href = '/index.html';
        }

    };
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

In AngularJs you can use a run function to listen to the `$stateChangeStart` event and take actions. As its name points its happens before the transition takes place and you can cancel or redirect to different place. This can be done at component level also.

```
angular.module('MyApp').run(canRedirect);
/** @ngInject */
function canRedirect($rootScope, $window, SomeService) {
    const stateChangeStart = $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', (event) => {
        // add your logic and take action
        if (SomeService.hasPermission()) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $window.location = '/path/to/redirect';
        }
    });
    $rootScope.$on('$destroy', canRedirect);
}
```